# Javascript - Parse cloud code dilemma

Tags: javascript, ios, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I have a code to check if every user is ready. Problem is this is done every 2 seconds in the app, draining a lot of req/s. The cloud code function is:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("UpdateWL", function(request, response) {
var _ = require('underscore');
var fbid = request.user.get("fbid");
var query = new Parse.Query("Spel");
query.equalTo("lobby", fbid);
query.find().then(function(results) {
    _.each(results, function(spel) {
        var a1 = spel.get("lobby");
        var a2 = spel.get("ready");
        if (a2.length >= a1.length) {
        var type = spel.get("type");
        if (type == "PEK") {
        response.success("showPEK");
        }else if (type == "CEL") {
        response.success("celeb") 
        }else if (type == "MIN") {
        response.success("minority")
        }else if (type == "CHAR") {
        response.success("charader")
        }}
    });
}), function(error) {
    response.error(error);
};
```

});

Where a1 is users in the lobby and a2 users who clicked ready.
I noticed that the time limit for cloud code execution is 15 sec. Therefore, is there a way to write this in a loop statement eg. while to instead call the cloud code function from the app every 15sec instead of every 2 seconds, since this will save a lot of req/s?

Kind regards,
Martin

Comment: Can you change the app-side request? If not, one way to limit the requests would be to keep track of the last time you made a request (e.g., in a seperate Class) and return early from the above cloud code function if it's within 15 seconds of the last call.

Comment: @liampronan yes but it's a multiplayer game so sometimes it takes 6 seconds for everyone to "readyup" and sometimes it takes three. Therefore I wonder if in Cloud Code you can write the above code with do { **get arrays and compare them** } while (array1.length > array2.length); and this has 15 seconds to timeout when if it breaks, a new one is called from the app.